# Can't install PHP 5.5 on CentOS 6.7

Tags: centos, php, installation, centos6

I have a dedicated server on [Kimsufi](http://www.kimsufi.com/en/). 
I am trying to update PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.5 on CentOS 6.7 using [this guide](https://www.mojowill.com/geek/howto-install-php-5-4-5-5-or-5-6-on-centos-6-and-centos-7/), but unfortunately i get the following errors:

```
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.4.45-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
       Requires: php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.45-1.el6.remi
       Removing: php-pdo-5.3.3-27.el6.2.x86_64 (@LocalRepo)
           php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6.2
       Updated By: php-pdo-5.5.29-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.5.29-1.el6.remi
       Available: php-pdo-5.4.44-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.44-1.el6.remi
       Available: php-pdo-5.4.45-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.45-1.el6.remi
       Available: php-pdo-5.5.28-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.5.28-1.el6.remi
       Available: php54w-pdo-5.4.44-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.44-1.w6
       Available: php55w-pdo-5.5.28-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.5.28-1.w6
       Available: php56w-pdo-5.6.12-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.6.12-1.w6
Error: Package: php-pecl-apc-3.1.9-2.el6.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: php(api) = 20090626
           Removing: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6.2.x86_64 (@LocalRepo)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Updated By: php-common-5.5.29-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.44-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.5.28-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: php54w-common-5.4.44-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php55w-common-5.5.28-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Installing: php56w-common-5.6.12-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
Error: Package: php-pecl-apc-3.1.9-2.el6.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Removing: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6.2.x86_64 (@LocalRepo)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Updated By: php-common-5.5.29-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.44-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.5.28-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: php54w-common-5.4.44-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php55w-common-5.5.28-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Installing: php56w-common-5.6.12-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

What do they mean exactly and how can i fix them?

Comment: Please supply the command you ran that got the error. It is not in fact anything to do with the Webtatic repository, but is something to do with a missmatch betweeen what you have already installed and the Remi repositories

Comment: You'd have better luck running `yum update php*` if using Remi repository

Comment: Here is the command: sudo yum install php php-gd php-mysql php-mcrypt

Comment: I tried what you said, `yum update php*`, but i get the same exact error...Any help?

Answer (score 3):

You have a conflicting repository named `webtatic` installed. Remove this repo (and any packages installed from it).

Once this is done, run `yum distro-sync` to sync your system to the latest versions of packages which are in the repositories.

At this point, you can install any additional packages you need.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please help me uninstalling them? What is the exact command? I'm afraid to mess everything up... Thanks

Comment: Hi! Any news? I am still stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no APC extension for PHP 5.5, you should switch to Zend Opcache instead.

I'm submitting a Webtatic answer as I'm the maintainer of it, and I dislike the lack of package pinning of Remi repository older RPMs, and the SCL new rpms. The former's way would have made this issue clearer as well.

As you have the Webtatic repo already installed, you can run:

```
yum install yum-plugin-replace
yum replace php-common --replace-with=php55w-common
yum install php55w-opcache
```

This can also be resolved another way if wanting to stick with Remi's php55 repo:

```
yum remove php-pecl-apc
yum update php*
yum install php-opcache
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work...when executing the command: `yum replace php-common --replace-with=php55w-common` i get this error: http://pastebin.com/0m57P7Rd ...what should i do? :(

Comment: Instead, if i try the second solution, when i run `yum update php*` i get this error: http://pastebin.com/w4i0Dtsf